# How to Create GA Events for Each Member of an Array in GTM

Tags: arrays, foreach, google-analytics

In our data layer, we have an array of add-ons for our products

```
Add-ons: [
{code: 'wheels', selection: 'alloy'),
{code: 'finish', selection: 'pearl'}
],
```

Unfortunately they are not the same for each product and are not returned in the same order.

We would like to create GA events for each add-on selected, using the code and selection in the array as the event Action and Label. So we need to loop through the array and create a new event for each item, and use the elements of the array in the event.

I created a GTM variable that pulls in the array (that works fine), but now I need to fire the event tracking. I've been working with forEach

```
<script>

  {{addon-list}}.forEach(function(arrayItem) {

dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'GAEvent',
    'eventCategory': 'AddOn',
    'eventAction': {{addon-list}}.code,
    'eventLabel': {{addon-list}}.selection,
    'nonInteraction': 1
})

});

</script>
```

While it fires one event, it is undefined for the Action and Label. Any ideas? This seems like a handy thing so I'm sure someone has done / is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Through a lot of iteration, I managed to arrive at a solution.

First, the GTM variable that pulls in the array needs to be version 1 because of how the data gets handled.

Then the script is:

```
<script>

  {{addon-list}}.forEach(createEvent);

  function createEvent (addon) {

dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'GAEvent',
    'eventCategory': 'AddOn',
    'eventAction': addon.code,
    'eventLabel': addon.selection,
    'nonInteraction': 1
})

};

</script>
```

By declaring the value of addon and using it in the variables to pull in the elements of the array, it worked.